# Using Command Lines Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, command-line

Dear Magento specialists,

I always had **Magento 1** running. However for my **new webshop** I like to run Magento 2. I have installed Magento 2 using Installatron. I extracted theme files in the root directory. However I am **trying to enable modules using command lines**. My hosting provider enabled SSH. I have to connect through a different port 7685. I can login using SSH, but no command will work. Could you guys help me? Thank you.

If I try to execute a command using terminal I get always No such file or directory

```
ssh Last login: Wed May 17 19:21:51 on console
MacBook-Pro-van-Rick:~ Rick$ ssh u2081p13512@sonsofadealer.com -p 7685
u2081p13512@sonsofadealer.com's password: 
[u2081p13512@web0114 ~]$ ls -l
totaal 12
drwx--x--x 3 u2081p13512 u2081p13512 4096 mei 12 20:12 domains
drwxrwx--- 3 u2081p13512 mail        4096 mei 12 20:12 imap
drwxrwx--- 2 u2081p13512 mail        4096 mei 12 20:12 Maildir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u2081p13512 u2081p13512   39 mei 12 20:12 public_html -> ./domains/sonsofadealer.com/public_html
[u2081p13512@web0114 ~]$ ll
totaal 12
drwx--x--x 3 u2081p13512 u2081p13512 4096 mei 12 20:12 domains
drwxrwx--- 3 u2081p13512 mail        4096 mei 12 20:12 imap
drwxrwx--- 2 u2081p13512 mail        4096 mei 12 20:12 Maildir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u2081p13512 u2081p13512   39 mei 12 20:12 public_html -> ./domains/sonsofadealer.com/public_html
[u2081p13512@web0114 ~]$ bin/magento module:enable Infortis_Base Infortis_Brands Infortis_Cgen Infortis_Dataporter Infortis_Infortis Infortis_Ultimo Infortis_UltraMegamenu Infortis_UltraSlideshow
-bash: bin/magento: No such file or directory
[u2081p13512@web0114 ~]$
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to go to directory where Magento has been installed to run Magento commands. I.e. you need to execute:

```
cd public_html/
```

before running:

```
bin/magento module:enable Infortis_Base Infortis_Brands Infortis_Cgen Infortis_Dataporter Infortis_Infortis Infortis_Ultimo Infortis_UltraMegamenu Infortis_UltraSlideshow
```

command.

Please let me know if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the php bin directly:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Infortis_Base Infortis_Brands Infortis_Cgen Infortis_Dataporter Infortis_Infortis Infortis_Ultimo Infortis_UltraMegamenu Infortis_UltraSlideshow
```

If you still can't find it, try to find it using one of the following commands:

```
locate bin/php
whereis php
```

If you're still having trouble, contact your hosting provider to check if your user is allowed to run PHP in CLI and if so, which php binary you should call